# Negative values in joy plot from non-negative data set

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, ridgeline-plot

I am creating a joyplot using joypy.

All my data is between[0,1].

But I get a big range of negative values in the graph:

[image]

[image]

```
import joypy
import pandas as pd
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
from matplotlib import cm
import matplotlib.ticker as ticker
import matplotlib
matplotlib.use('TkAgg')


iris = pd.read_csv("1_5.csv")

fig, axes = joypy.joyplot(iris)


x = [0,0.25,0.5,0.75,1]

plt.xticks(x)

plt.show()
```

Comment: A joyplot is a representative of a distribution or density function. The tails of most statisitical distributions go beyond the range of the actual values. In your case, you can see that the distribution quickly approaches 0 in the negative direction as one would expect.

Comment: I think [this question](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/109549/negative-density-for-non-negative-variables) best answers the underlying concern.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It isn't clear that your xticks are in any way tied to the actual joyplot itself (ie, you've created arbitrary x-ticks and placed them on the plot).

Are tick marks not represented on the plot originally (similar plots I've seen all have them by default)?

Comment: Why do you think that 0 on the axis does not correspond to 0 in the data? In any case, OP hasn't created arbitrary xticks at all. They just labelled arbitrary positions on the axis, which is fine to bring the point of the question accross.

Comment: Sorry I was given confusing instruction, I remade the data set now it's working